# Unknown pads on board

Tags: spi, flash, reverse-engineering

I'm analyzing a board for some device (game handheld console). I've found a simple SPI flash on it (W25Q) but there are 2 pads exposed for what I assume is factory testing (there are no other pads exposed on the whole board). The thing is, those pads are the ones for `/CS` and `DO`. However, as far as I know you cannot get anything out of the chip without driving both `CLK` and sending a command through `DI`, so I just wanted to know if this makes sense from an engineering perspective, or it might be just something that will probably be driven by the main CPU or something.

[image: W25Q chip with pads]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/949/w25q32jv_revg_03272018_plus-1760028.pdf) (assuming you're right about the W25Q), these are the *Chip Select* and *data out* pins.

So, you're right, on their own, probably not useful. Might still be an important test point where the ability of a controller to initialize itself and read identification from the flash might be tested.

Also, note that this might be something that's "dual use", if the controller supports it: for example, on boards where the flash is not soldered on (which exists - otherwise the larger unpopulated footprint makes no sense), this might be testing something completely different.

Comment: Well spotted; the larger footprint looks like it would suit a parallel Flash of some sort.

Comment: And the test pads are carefully sited outside the larger footprint, so... it may be that whoever wrote the test plan figured those signals could not be tested in some configuration by other means (JTAG etc) so asked the layout engineer for direct access.

Comment: Yeah, there is place for another flash in there, although I don't think there is a connection between any of the "new" pads & those testing pads. I guess we'll never know, but your guess is as good as any, I suppose! Thanks!